# For finite-duration continuous $f(t)$ with $\|f'(t)\|_\infty < \infty$: It is true $\|f'(t)\|_\infty \leq \frac{2\pi \|f'(t)\|_2^2}{\|f'(t)\|_1}$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, upper-lower-bounds, integral-inequality, finite-duration

**For finite-duration continuous $f(t)$ with bounded derivative $\|f'(t)\|_\infty < \infty$: It is true that $\|f'(t)\|_\infty \leq \frac{2\pi \|f'(t)\|_2^2}{\|f'(t)\|_1}$?**

I am looking for an **upper bound for the derivative** of finite-duration continuous functions $f(t)$ that have bounded derivative $\|f'(t)\|_\infty <\infty$ (with unknown upper bound), but with $f'(t)$ discontinuous, but at most in finitely many zero-measure points, where also $f(t)$ has a convergent Fourier Transform $\hat{f}(w)$.

For continuous functions with at most a finite amount of discontinuities in $f'(t)$ the traditional upper bound $\|f'(t)\|_\infty \leq \|w\hat{f}(w)\|_1$ wouldn´t properly work, since it will diverge $\|w\hat{f}(w)\|_1 \to \infty$ for bounded but discontinuous $f'(t)$.

As example, think in $f(t)=\sin(\pi|t|),\,|t|\leq 1$: here $f(t)$ is continuous but has a "pike" at $t=0$, where $f'(t)$ is discontinuous having a jump-discontinuity changing from $-\pi$ to $+\pi$, but the size of the jump is bounded so it stills fulfill $|f'(t)| \leq \pi < \infty$... different from the counterexample $f(t) = |t\,\log(t^2)|(1-t^2+|1-t^2|)$ which also has a "pike" at $t=0$ but $f'(t)$ diverges here.

Since I know that $\|f'(t)\|_\infty \leq \|w\hat{f}(w)\|_1$ doesn´t work for discontinuous but bounded $f'(t)$, I was trying to found another alternative of upper bound for these cases (for other cases, or $f'(t)$ is unbounded, or I already have the mentioned upper bound), and I believe I have found the following upper bound using Parseval's Identity for the derivative:
$$\begin{array}{c}
\|f'\|_2^2 = \frac{1}{2\pi}\|w\hat{f}\|_2^2 \overset{\text{Hölder}\,p=1}{\leq} \frac{1}{2\pi} \|w\hat{f}\|_\infty \cdot \|w\hat{f}\|_1 \leq \frac{1}{2\pi} \|f'\|_1\cdot \|w\hat{f}\|_1 \\
\overset{\text{norms}\geq 0}{\Rightarrow} \frac{2\pi \|f'(t)\|_2^2}{\|f'(t)\|_1} \leq \|w\hat{f}\|_1
\end{array}$$

So I want to know if is possible to compare both lower bounds of $\|w\hat{f}\|_1$ between each other, **hopefully** fulfilling that is true that:
$\|f'(t)\|_\infty \leq \frac{2\pi \|f'(t)\|_2^2}{\|f'(t)\|_1}$
for **functions with already bounded $\mathbf{\|f'(t)\|_\infty <\infty}$** (this is important: I already know **is false in general**, so there are many examples for which $\|f'(t)\|_\infty \to \infty$ and the bound will be finite $\frac{2\pi \|f'(t)\|_2^2}{\|f'(t)\|_1} < \infty$)...

So, my idea is:

1. Test first $\|w\hat{f}(w)\|_1$,
2. And then, If the bound (1) diverges, test second (2) $\frac{2\pi \|f'(t)\|_2^2}{\|f'(t)\|_1} $ as an upper bound.

I have already tested it working for these function that rises in the answers to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4320245/are-there-functions-ft-with-ft-infty-infty-such-as-their-fourie) question: $f(t)=1−|t|,\,|t|\leq 1$  and $f(t)=e^{−|t|},\,|t|\leq1$.

**Note 1:** I know beforehand that these bounds are not really practical and are sometimes harder than finding directly $\|f'\|_\infty$, but I am trying to understand which characteristics of a finite-duration function will make its derivatives to be unbounded or bounded.

**Note 2:** Take in consideration that I am asking about continuous functions that are of **finite-duration**, so by the [Extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) I have already that the function is bounded $\|f(t)\|_\infty < \infty$.

**Note 3:** I already know that I have $\|f'\|_\infty \leq \|w\hat{f}\|_1$ and $\frac{2\pi \|f'\|_2^2}{\|f'\|_1} \leq \|w\hat{f}\|_1$ **does not imply** $ \|f'\|_\infty \leq \frac{2\pi \|f'\|_2^2}{\|f'\|_1}$, I am asking If it is possible to prove that only for scenarios where $\|f'\|_\infty < \infty$, then IF $ \|f'\| \leq \frac{2\pi \|f'\|_2^2}{\|f'\|_1}$ could be used as an upper bound, since I have found some examples where it works (maybe is an accident), these to see if there is an alternative upper bound for scenarios of bounded derivative where $\|w\hat{f}\|_1 \to \infty$.

---

**Example:**

Lets work with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4320245/909869) example (2nd comment by @Lorenzo Pompili), given by the [function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot++e%5E%28-%7Ct%7C%29+from+t%3D-1+to+1):

$f(t) = \begin{cases} e^{-|t|}, & \,|t|\leq 1 \\ 0, & \,|t|>1 \end{cases}$

Its [derivative](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=+D%5Be%5E%28-%7Ct%7C%29%2Ct%5D) is going to be $f'(t) = -\frac{t}{|t|}e^{-|t|},\,|t|\leq 1$ so I will have for this example that the derivative it will be [bounded by](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sup+%7CD%5Be%5E%28-%7Ct%7C%29%2Ct%5D%7C) $\sup_t |f'| = 1 << \infty$, even when [its discontinuous](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot++-t%2F%7Ct%7C*e%5E%28-%7Ct%7C%29+from+t%3D-1+to+1).

Now, being proved is bounded, I will take now the [Finite Extension Fourier Transform](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int_%7B-1%7D%5E%7B1%7D+e%5E%28-%7Ct%7C%29*e%5E%28-i*w*t%29*dt) of $f(t)$:
$$\hat{f}(w) = \int\limits_{-1}^{1} e^{-|t|}e^{-iwt}dt = \frac{e^{-(1+iw)}\left( 2\,e^{1+iw}+iw-1-(1+iw)e^{2iw}\right)}{1+w^2}$$

So, I will try to compute the [classic upper bound](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Nintegrate%5B+%7Cw*%28e%5E%28-1+-+i+w%29+%28-1+%2B+2+e%5E%281+%2B+i+w%29+%2B+e%5E%282+i+w%29+%28-1+-+i+w%29+%2B+i+w%29%29%2F%281+%2B+w%5E2%29%7C%2C%7Bw%2C+-inf%2C+inf%7D%5D):
$$\|w\hat{f}(w)\|_\infty = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} |w\hat{f}(w)|dw \to \infty$$
but since $f'(t)$ is discontinuous it show to diverge, so it don´t going to help as an upper bound (at least as a tight-as-possible one).

Now to see if there is something that can be done using the bound I am asking to prove if it could work for these scenarios where $\|w\hat{f}(w)\|_\infty \to \infty$, lets calculate it by each of its components:

- $$\|f'(t)\|_2^2 = \int\limits_{-1}^1 \left|-\frac{t}{|t|}e^{-|t|} \right|^2 dt = 1 - \frac{1}{e^2} < \infty$$ ([here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int_%7B-1%7D%5E%7B1%7D+%7C-t%2F%7Ct%7C*e%5E%28-%7Ct%7C%29%7C%5E2*dt))
- $$\|f'(t)\|_1 =  \int\limits_{-1}^1 \left|-\frac{t}{|t|}e^{-|t|} \right| dt = 2 - \frac{2}{e} < \infty $$ ([here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int_%7B-1%7D%5E%7B1%7D+%7C-t%2F%7Ct%7C*e%5E%28-%7Ct%7C%29%7C*dt))
- $$\frac{2\pi\|f'(t)\|_2^2}{\|f'(t)\|_1}=2\pi\frac{\left(1 - \frac{1}{e^2}\right)}{\left(2 - \frac{2}{e}\right)}= \frac{\pi(1+e)}{e} \approx 4.3 << \infty $$ ([here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=2*pi*%281-1%2Fe%5E2%29%2F%282-2%2Fe%29))

So at least for this example the "happy accident" of
$$ \|f'(t)\|_\infty = 1 \quad < \quad  4.3 = \frac{2\pi\|f'(t)\|_2^2}{\|f'(t)\|_1} \quad  << \quad  \infty = \|w\hat{f}(w)\|_\infty$$
happen to be true, working as a tightest upper bound for the rate of change than  $\|w\hat{f}(w)\|_\infty$.

This is why, knowing beforehand it is false in general, I want to know if there is a way to prove/disprove if this happy accident could be used for the cases where  $\|w\hat{f}(w)\|_\infty \to \infty$ as an alternative tighter upper bound for the maximum rate of change.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking: You say (if I'm understanding correctly?) that you have examples of sequences $(f_n)$ with $\| f_n'\|_{\infty}\to \infty$, but uniformly bounded quotient $\| f_n'\|_2^2/\| f_n'\|_1$. This precludes the inequality in the title from being true. Could you clarify this a little?

Comment: @Jose27 Thanks for commenting. I have changed the redaction trying to make it understandable. I am afraid is different from what you have understood, but since I am ignorant about sequences I don´t really know how to presented it on these terms.

Comment: @Jose27 I think you understood what he is asking, and this indeed is false for the reasons you say.

Comment: Maybe I am mistaken, is what I am trying to figure out. Unfortunately I don´t fully understand what you are saying, but I have added an example of what I am trying to do. Hope it could make clear what I am trying to prove/disprove.

Comment: @Jose27 Does the last example fulfill what you mention about sequences? I wan´t to know If I am asking a valid question or if it is just a nonsense?