# An example that does not satisfy the conditions of the Fourier inversion theorem?

Tags: fourier-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Here is the [Fourier inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem) page in Wikipedia.

It states that for every function $f(x)$ that satisfy some conditions ($f(x)$ can be a function such as *a Schwartz function, an integrable function in one dimension, or a square integrable function*), $\mathcal F^{-1} (\mathcal F f) = f$ where $\mathcal F$ is the Fourier transform.

What I want to find is a function $g(x)$ such that $\mathcal F^{-1} (\mathcal F g) \neq g$. The conditions in the Wikipedia page seem to be somewhat *sufficient* conditions, and I can't come up with such $g(x)$.

Is there any conceivable function $g(x)$?

Comment: Here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66173/integrable-function-whose-fourier-transform-is-not-integrable

Comment: and it depends on your definition of the Fourier transform. with the Fourier transform of distributions, you can assign a well-defined Fourier transform and a Fourier inversion theorem for much more functions than the integrable or square-integrable ones.