# Does Fourier Transform preserve $L^1$-convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Consider $f,\mathscr F f \in L^1(\mathbf R^n)$. Dominated convergence theorem implies that
$$\mathscr F[f(x)]\cdot \mathbf 1_{|x|\le R}\overset{L_1}{\longrightarrow} \mathscr F[f(x)]$$
But what can be said about $$g_R=\mathscr F[f(x)\mathbf 1_{|x|\le R}]$$
Definitely $g_R\in L^1$ but do these functions converge to $\mathscr F[f]$ in $L_1$?

If $f\in L^2$ it's well-known that $\mathscr F[f(x)\mathbf 1_{|x|\le R}]\overset{L_2}{\longrightarrow}\mathscr F[f].$

I believe that these functions do not have to converge to Fourier transform, so I should construct a counterexample, but I struggle with it, so any hint is appreciated! Thanks!

P.S. I think the example shoud also be 1-dimensional, but trivial attempt to check exponents like $e^{-x^2} $ didnt work, as soon as integral over finite interval has no elementary formula.

Comment: The Fourier transform of an $L^1$ function does not need to be $L^1$: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/66173/1104384

Comment: The Fourier transform of $f\in L^1$ may not belong to $L^1.$ It holds if $f$ is smooth enough.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc, I edited my question. Sorry for not being specific and long answer

Comment: If $f\in L^1(\Bbb{R}^n)$ then $\hat{f} = \mathscr{F} f \in C_0(\Bbb{R}^n)$ and $\|\hat{f}\|_\infty\le\|f\|_1$.  So if $\|f_n - f\|_1\to 0$ then $\|\hat{f}_n - \hat{f}\|_\infty \le \|f_n - f\|_1 \to 0$.

Comment: @JohnDoe, but uniform convergence does not imply $L_1$ convergence in our case?

Comment: @BigCoconut:  No.  Like you've been told it's possible none of $\hat{f_n}, \hat{f}$ are in $L^1$.

Comment: @JohnDoe, yes, it's clear, the hard part for me is to understand what happens in case $\hat f\in L^1$. It implies $g_R\in L^1$ and then I have to figure out more delicate argument why there's no convergence in particular case